# Differential Sortino Ratio

Tags: sharpe-ratio, machine-learning, differential-equations

I'm attempting to optimize a reinforcement learning system to maximize risk adjusted returns. I have currently defined the reward as the differential Sharpe ratio at each step: the influence of the return at time t on the cumulative Sharpe ratio.

This was defined in [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/93b8/17deef9dd5afc66ccf43174a07ddaa49854f.pdf) paper [Reinforcement Learning for Trading, by John 
Moody and Matthew Saffell, NIPS, 1999], however I am interested in maximizing Sortino ratio instead. The assets I am trading are highly volatile but also heavily skewed towards positive returns; the Sharpe ratio of the strategy is only 2.5 but the Sortino is ~11. So, maximizing for Sharpe here doesn't make much sense. The derivation of this differential Sharpe ratio is:
[image]

I would like to adapt this only take into account the variance of my downside risk. Any help or further reading would be great.

Comment: It is not clear that maximizing Sharpe "doesn't make much sense". Upside variation can induce "lost opportunity cost" regret in an investor.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution for this, I am facing the same problem.